# Accessing nested object from JSON when it is a dynamic number represented as string

Tags: json, swift, xcode, api, jsondecoder

I'm accessing the data from an API with XCode(10.2.1) and Swift(5.0) and ran into a problem I cannot seem to find the answer to. I am able to get data from all other parts of the API apart from one, which has been named as a number string "750", im not sure how to grab that data when I can't use a variable that jsonDecoder can read?

This is an example of what I know won't work but gives you an idea of what I'm trying to do.

```
class Images: Codable {
    let "750": String

    init("750": String){
        self."750" = "750"
    }
}
```

Here's a snippet from the API I'm trying to get the images from:

```
  "id": "069f7f26",
      "sku": "AP",
      "title": "Pizza",
      "description": "A really great pizza",
      "list_price": "9.95",
      "is_vatable": true,
      "is_for_sale": false,
      "age_restricted": false,
      "box_limit": 2,
      "always_on_menu": false,
      "volume": null,
      "zone": null,
      "created_at": "2017-03-06T10:52:43+00:00",
      "attributes": [
        {
          "id": "670f0e7c",
          "title": "Allergen",
          "unit": null,
          "value": "Products manufactured in a nut environment"
        },
        {
          "id": "c29e7",
          "title": "Weight",
          "unit": "g",
          "value": "300"
        }
      ],
      "tags": [

      ],
      "images": {
        "750": {
          "src": "https:\/\/some_website.co.uk\/cms\/product_image\some_image.jpg",
          "url": "https:\/\/some_website.co.uk\/cms\/product_image\some_image.jpg",
          "width": 750
        }
      }
    },
```

Comment: Solution below by Denis should work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I setup an example that better match your situation in order to give you an overview on how to `parse` and access your `JSON` information dynamically with a `Dictionary` data type:

```
import Foundation

let jsonData = """
{
    "images": {
        "750": {
          "src": "https:\\/\\/some_website.co.uk/cms/product_image/some_image.jpg",
          "url": "https:\\/\\/some_website.co.uk/cms/product_image/some_image.jpg",
          "width": 750
        }
    }
}
"""

let json = jsonData.data(using: .utf8)!

public struct Results: Codable {
    public var images: [String:Image] = [:]

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case images = "images"
    }
}

public struct Image: Codable {
    public var src: String = ""
    public var url: String = ""
    public var width: Int = 0

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case src = "src"
        case url = "url"
        case width = "width"
    }
}

if let results = try? JSONDecoder().decode(Results.self, from: json) {
    let imagesDict = results.images
    for (key, value) in imagesDict {
        print("Key: \(key)")
        print("Value: \(value)")
    }
}
```

If you try this snippet it will give you this output printed:

```
Key: 750
Value: Image(src: "https://some_website.co.uk/cms/product_image/some_image.jpg", url: "https://some_website.co.uk/cms/product_image/some_image.jpg", width: 750)
```

You can try out the snippet above online, if you copy paste it here and run it: http://online.swiftplayground.run/

**### UPDATE (in response to comment)**

In response to your comment, I found it easier to setup another example to show you how you can achieve that with your exact code sample that you shared in the comment itself.

I left everything as class and just added `images` in order to leave you an overview on how to achieve that.

In the end, I'd suggest to rename `Products` and `Attributes` into `Product` and `Attribute`. Also if there is no strong reason on why you choosed the `model` to be `class`, just change them to `struct` and as well if there is no strong reasons to keep most of the attributes of each model `optional` give them a default value as I did in the example above if you are always expecting some values/attributes to be there.

You can try and run this snippet as well in http://online.swiftplayground.run to try it out:

```
import Foundation

let jsonData = """
{
    "data": [
        {
            "title": "titlex",
            "description": "descx",
            "list_price": "123,456",
            "attributes": [
                {
                    "title": "titlex",
                    "unit": "unitx",
                    "value": "valuex"
                }
            ],
            "images": {
                "750": {
                "src": "https:\\/\\/some_website.co.uk/cms/product_image/some_image.jpg",
                "url": "https:\\/\\/some_website.co.uk/cms/product_image/some_image.jpg",
                "width": 750
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
"""

let json = jsonData.data(using: .utf8)!

class AllProducts: Codable {
    let data: [Products]

    init(data: [Products]) {
        self.data = data
    }
}

class Products: Codable {
    let title: String?
    let description: String?
    let list_price: String?
    let attributes: [Attributes]?
    let images: [String:Image]?

    init(title: String, description: String, list_price: String, attributes: [Attributes], images: [String:Image]) {
        self.title = title
        self.description = description
        self.list_price = list_price
        self.attributes = attributes
        self.images = images
    }
}

class Attributes: Codable {
    let title: String?
    let unit: String?
    let value: String?

    init(title: String, unit: String, value: String) {
        self.title = title
        self.unit = unit
        self.value = value
    }
}

class Image: Codable {
    let src: String?
    let url: String?
    let width: Int?

    init(src: String, url: String, width: Int) {
        self.src = src
        self.url = url
        self.width = width
    }
}

// parsing/decoding
if let results = try? JSONDecoder().decode(AllProducts.self, from: json) {
    if let imagesDict = results.data[0].images {

    // there is an "images" for product at position 0 (the only one in my json example)
        for (key, value) in imagesDict {
            print("Key: \(key)")
            print("Value src: \(value.src)")
            print("Value url: \(value.url)")
            print("Value width: \(value.width)")
        }
    }
}
```

Output

```
Key: 750
Value src: Optional("https://some_website.co.uk/cms/product_image/some_image.jpg")
Value url: Optional("https://some_website.co.uk/cms/product_image/some_image.jpg")
Value width: Optional(750)
```

Comment: Thanks @denis_lor. This looks great but I'm having difficulty transposing it to my current codebase. I guess the problem I really have is that there are over 400 items I am trying to sort through and put into a table view. Heres what I currently have. [https://www.codepile.net/pile/vA1pDJyN](https://www.codepile.net/pile/vA1pDJyN)